# Fortran MPI code open different files with the same unit number

Tags: io, fortran, mpi

I'm running a fortran code in multi processes using Open MPI. Each process needs to open and write many files. During the run time, it's possible that two different processes will open and write different files with the same `unit` number concurrently.

```
processA: open(unit=10, file1)
processB: open(unit=10, file2)
```

Will this cause a problem?

Comment: Note that MPI is no the same as OpenMPI. The latter is just one of many implementations of the former.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and no it should not cause problems. The MPI processes all live on their own and are not aware of the memory (and therefore unit numbers) of other processes. Though you should be careful to not create too many files, if you use thousands of processes you may run into limitations of the filesystem.

Comment: I understand that variables of different processes live in their own address space and do not communicate with each other unless MPI subroutine is called. I'm not sure about files which involves I/O of the system. Apparently, if two process open the same file (same filename), this will cause a problem. And could you talk more about the relationship between the unit number and memory allocated? I try to understand things thoroughly from the hardware level.

Comment: The unit is just a handle for the file descriptor, which the process holds in its memory to refer to the file. It is not directly related to something on the disk.